# How to convert text to UTF-8 encoding within a text file

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, utf-8, type-conversion

When I use a text editor to see the actual content, I see

```
baliÄ<8d>ky 0 b a l i ch k i
```

and when I use cat to see it, I see

```
baličky 0 b a l i ch k i
```

How can I make it so, it is actually `baličky` in the text editor as well?

I've tried numerous commands such as `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-15`, `iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8`, `recode utf8..l9`.

None of them works. It's still `baliÄ<8d>ky` instead of `baličky`. This is a Czech word. If I do a simple sed command (/Ä<8d>/č), it works but I have so many other characters like this and manual work is basically really mundane at this point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What editor is it? It seems that it doesn't support UTF-8

Comment: ` in the text editor` You should configure your text editor, not change the file.

Comment: @Fravadona its VIM, it does support UTF-8

Comment: @KamilCuk, I think those characters are not UTF-8, as my VIM is already configured with UTF-8

Comment: `I think those characters are not UTF-8` Why do you think that? Let's confirm it - please post the output of `cat yourfile | hexdump -C`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I get this ```00000000  62 61 6c 69 c4 8d 6b 79  20 30 20 62 20 61 20 6c  |bali..ky 0 b a l|```

Comment: @KamilCuk hmm why doesn't my VIM display these properly, I've set it as encoding=utf-8 as well as fileencoding=utf-8

Comment: @KamilCuk So here's a strange behavior. When I ```cat``` my file I get ```baličky 0 b a l i ch k i```. When I use ```vim``` to see it, I get ```baliÄ<8d>ky 0 b a l i ch k i```. Now when I copy the output of ```cat``` and open a new file with VIM, and paste it I get ```baličky 0 b a l i ch k i``` in both VIM and just regular cat command. What changed?

Comment: @JoeyJoestar if you save the copy/pasted file, what does `diff original.txt copypasted,txt` says about it?

Comment: @Fravadona, following your suggestion I just tested it on one file but strangely, it just worked. My vim displayed the chracters as is. However, I think there is a non-utf chracter in my big txt file that's causing this. when I do ```grep -axv '.*' TEST1.txt``` I get ```� 0 �```. So I think I'd just get rid of those

Comment: Can you post the result of `hexdump -C yourfile` ?

Comment: Your file is `UTF-8`: byte sequence `C4 8D` is `č` (U+010D,  *Latin Small Letter C With Caron*), see https://unicode-table.com/en/010D/.

Comment: Make sure you are using a UTF-8 terminal and locale, e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`. Then UTF-8 text should display just fine in ~all 21. century editors. A side note about the Czech word: Are you sure it is *bal**i**čky* (== *female workers of a packaging facility*) rather than *bal**í**čky* (== *packages*)?